# Akka routing actor when the routee wants to change the routing

Tags: akka

Please note the following description is for illustration purposes only. The question is about patterns for event stream processing in akka not a question about how to solve the illustrative example with alternative designs.

Imagine a complex event processing engine written in Akka where the event rules are modelled by actors. The event flow of messages are things similar to orders, fulfilment of items within orders, payments against orders. The business rules actors are doing something similar to invoicing the customers and tracking the payments until completion. The data which the business rules are interested in is extremely dynamic in nature where it is not possible to know which rules are tracking which parts of the message stream.

Naively one could use a boardcast router style approach. All business rules actors would see all of the data and they would ignore the message if it was not data that they where tracking. Yet this would have scalability issues as not all rules actors are interested in all data by a very significant proportion. This implies using an index of which rules actors are tracking which types of messages by the complex business identifiers within the messages. Then we can only send the rules actors the data which they are looking out for. This index of which messages go to which actors changes in response to the business rules within the actors. Looking at this from the perspective of a routing actor then the routee is wanting to change the route dynamically.

This gives rise to a timing issue. If the routing actor is running fast enough to keep many routees busy then it will have passed a stream of messages, say {A,B,C}, through by the time one particular routee gets message {A}. If that routee then decides that it needs message {B} then it will already have been routed upstream of it but not to the mailbox of the routee which lately discovered it now wants message {B} having seen message {A}. The modified route would only take effect on messages after {C} or more likely much later when the routing actor gets around to processing the response message from the particular routee.

One solution to this is to buffer the messages at the routing actor. Then if a routee changes what it is interested in response to a message then the routing actor can scan the buffer of old messages and resend some as required. This implies a lot of code to keep the buffer of messages as small as possible to be able to resend them as efficient as possible. I am wondering if there is a more standard pattern or more natural approach to solving dynamic routing within Akka?

[Footnote: Alternative solutions as described in the comments are to use a cache of messages and have the rules actors hit the cache but lets assume that the cache would have to be very large forcing IO or two phase commit with the main jdbc store so assume that a cache is undesirable if it can possible be avoided. The question is about event streaming patterns in akka where the routing rules can change in a highly dynamic manner - the approximate description of such a system above is simplified and for illustrative purposes only. The key paragrah is about the message stream {A,B,C} and having a route read {A} decide that it then needs message {B} which has already been dispatched by the upstream router.]

Comment: Question, does each event/message to be processed have an ID & can your application explicitly say I have message ID=A I need message ID=B? Based on your current design, perhaps you have an aggregator which maintains a list of IDs and is aware of potential side effects and forwards messages to other actors if needed. The other option would be to try and group your pipe line as much as possible so you broadcast to a limit number of actors and that actor chain makes its own decisions on where to send messages next.

Comment: @NightWolf The new akka software is the aggregator who's job it is to have business rules to work out which messages are related and act upon them. So the problem cannot be simplified to know which messages are related before sending them to the rules actors. The peak burst volume of events will be very high so a fan out pipeline is required. The routing actor should hold an index of which rules are tracking which messages by what business keys on the messages. Then the challenge is as outlined in the question: how to efficiently have routees update that index.

Comment: Im not sure I completely understand why you need to have one routing actor. It sounds like RuleActorX is making a decision that the routing state needs to change. To me this sounds like enrichment. If the RuleActorX decides that it needs more data then it should request this by sending a message to some re-router or explicitly get the message from storage. Perhaps you could use an agent for managing the state change rather than buffering messages which seems  risky.

Comment: You are correct that rules actors currently go to mongodb for the data when we change what they wish to see. I have an akka solution which works in a normal persist-then-query mode but we want to scale up to do tens or hundreds of millions of messages so are looking at a more realtime in-memory event stream processing model with minimal io. My question is the akka or actor patterns to do "real time continuous query where downstream actors have upstream actors change routes with zero io".

Comment: Something like an LRU cache?

Comment: We have a cache actor used exactly as you describe. Future peak loads of daily rollovers of the market prices and foreign exchange will saturate cache IO. I want to bulk jdbc query then stream some daily data into the rules actors to avoid chatty cache use on the very large event spikes. Is there an akka pattern to have routees efficiently update their routes? The system description given is very simplified. The ideas above are good and do work as we currently do them. My question is about event streaming patterns in akka to possibly improve upon an already working design.

Comment: @NightWolf i have modified the question to be clearer - my apologies that i had originally asked for alternative solutions but was not clear that i was looking for routing solutions not alternative system designs. Your questions and comments are very valid thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Dynamic routing is a state change. So really, if the message has passed through the system AFAIK there is no 'Akka' way to get the message back & resend. You'd need to manage a buffer/cache. After all, routers are just actors which manage a set of actor refs. If your routers are distributed look at Akka clustering and A consensus/agreement algo to share router state. You may also find something in Eventsourced https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced Otherwise to manage the router state changes you could use Agents. You can wait for all updates to be applied before sending messages further.

Comment: The other option would be to simply broadcast all messages to all local actors. So you'd have all of your rule actors running on each node and shard the messages between nodes. Message passing between actors is relatively cheap when you're not sending messages over the network. If you could create a set of filter actors which sit over the rules actors and throw away messages they dont need quickly/cheaply before they do any processing then it may be a simpler design choice.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be fairly general. I see here two subproblems

1. It may benefit from rules decomposition. If it is possible to create a "correlation token" (customer id, initial order id) then some intermediate actor can do very good initial routing (based on hash of the token for instance). Then finally the ultimate actor can select what it needs from much smaller set of messages.
2. For constructing general purpose event-handling topology with sophisticated rules one may consider a library [SynapseGrid](https://github.com/Primetalk/SynapseGrid/). It has a builder for constructing the topology that is then converted to the runtime system of interconnected actors. The rules are either as simple as Scala functions or as complex as complete subsystem branch with nested actors.